# java awt.print not printing string

Tags: java, printing, awt

I need to print a string to a printer using java print utility.
I can see the job created in my printer but nothing gets printed.
Even when I try to change the printer to PDF, the PDF is generated blank.

I am trying to print a string value only.

```
String is="Hello\f";

PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
pras.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); 
pras.add(new Copies(1)); 

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is.getBytes("UTF8"), flavor, null);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
job.print(doc, pras);
```

Any idea what am I performing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using something else than DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE ?

Do you have something printed if you do this :

```
            InputStream is=null;
            try {
                String printString = "Hello\f";
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(printString.getBytes("UTF8"));                    
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                ...
            }

            PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(1));
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
            DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
```

Comment: yes, i tried the autosense and didn't work; the above snippet didn't work even. nothing getting printed. i can see the job in the printer queue and the file size but nothing is triggered. also if i change the printer to PDF it doesn't recognize the format.

Comment: Well you can still try with this piece of code, https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-print-a-string-using-javax-print-api.html then If it still doesn't work, you can be sure it's something about your printer settings

Comment: i tried this code beforehand and didn't work and also other users experienced the same problem without written resolution. but the issue is that even while trying to print to pdf, the file is empty. not sure what is the issue out there.